# Mulit-Dimensional ImageView?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I'm making a 2D Tile Engine for Android. I'd like to know how to make a Multi-Dimensional ImageView (Like any other multidimensional value).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've understood but I give a try..

You want to draw something that depends on a parameter? Example: a sprite in a videogames that depends on time?

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html